# Is it possible in QML to add button to the window system menu?

Tags: qt, menu, qml

I want to add button to the window main panel (where there are a buttons close-resize-move window).

Please dont propose to draw all window by myself (without using window class).

Is it possible in qml somehow, maybe redefine window slass or draw menu bar over the window menu? Any ideas are wellcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible since the window bar is a native thing and not rendered in the qml flow. There are some flags on qwindow that allow you to modify them a bit but thats as far as it goes. I would suggest digging into your OS-specific API (you didn't specify wich os) to see if it can be done.

Comment: OS is Windows. Now i'm searching for the API nesessary functions )